# Java assertion when tried to generate signed apk

Tags: flutter, dart, intellij-idea

```
java.lang.AssertionError
  at org.jetbrains.android.exportSignedPackage.ExportSignedPackageWizard.createAndAlignApk(ExportSignedPackageWizard.java:473)
  at org.jetbrains.android.exportSignedPackage.ExportSignedPackageWizard$1.run(ExportSignedPackageWizard.java:162)
  at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.startTask(CoreProgressManager.java:450)
  at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.startTask(ProgressManagerImpl.java:117)
  at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcessWithProgressAsync$5(CoreProgressManager.java:510)
  at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$3(ProgressRunner.java:243)
  at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:183)
  at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:705)
  at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:647)
  at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:63)
  at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:170)
  at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:243)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
  at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: i have tried  updating gradle to 7.2 and updateded dart and flutter plugins

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the complete logs attached (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data). A sample project to reproduce would help as well.

Comment: Reported  at youtrack.jetbrains